# inserting multiple rows through stored proc using XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

I am trying following stored proc to insert attendance of whole class(multiple student) at one go.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_add_attendanceByLectureId] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @pLectureId int,
    @pUsersXml xml  
AS
BEGIN
   --SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO AcademicAttendance(StudentId, LectureId, [Status])      
    select M.Item.value('StudentId[1]','INT') as StudentId, -- here error occured
    @pLectureId as LectureId,
    M.Item.value('Status','BIT') as [Status]
    FROM @pUsersXml.nodes('/ArrayOfStudnts/Student') AS M(Item)

END
```

While creating above sp following error occured

Msg 2389, Level 16, State 1, Procedure usp_add_attendanceByLectureId, Line 17
XQuery [value()]: 'value()' requires a singleton (or empty sequence), found operand of type 'xdt:untypedAtomic *'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
M.Item.value('Status[1],'BIT') as [Status]
```

instead of

```
M.Item.value('Status','BIT') as [Status]
```

Comment: We always do silly mistake, but it's good to take help from others when we are frustrating.